# Vue parent component doesn't recognize emit from child

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to make a website which features multiple cards and when a card is selected it should expand.
The code from the card component is:

```
<template>
  
  <v-card
    class="mx-auto"
    max-width="90%"
    min-height="600"
    app
    @click="selectCard(id)"
  >
    <!-- <img v-bind:src="img" /> -->
    
    <v-img
      dark
      class="white--text align-end"
      height="400px"
      :src="require('../assets/' + img)"
      :alt="`${title}`"
      
    >
    </v-img>
    <v-card-title>
      <p class="text-wrap">{{title}}</p>
    </v-card-title>
    
    <v-card-subtitle class="pb-0">{{taglist}}</v-card-subtitle>

    <v-card-text class="text--primary">
      <div>{{text}}</div>
    </v-card-text>

    <v-card-actions>

      <v-btn
        color="orange"
        text
        @click="selectCard(id)"
      >
        Read More
      </v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</template>


<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Card',
    computed: {
      taglist() {
        let list = "";
        for (let t of this.tags) {
          list = list + t + ", ";
        // console.log("TEST:" + (1===this.id))
        }
        
        list = list.substring(0, list.length-2);
        return list;
      }
    },
    methods: {
      selectCard(id) {
        this.$emit('expandCard',id)
      }
    },
    
    props: {
      title: String,
      tags: Array,
      img: String,
      text: String,
      id: Number,
    }
  }
</script>
```

And the parent component that should be listening is:

```
<template>
  <div class="projects">
    
    <v-main>
      <v-row>
        <v-col 
          cols="12"
          sm="6"
          md="4"
          lg="4"
          v-for="data in info"
          :key="data.index"
          
        >
          <Card 
            :title="data.title"
            :tags="data.tags"
            :img="data.img"
            :text="data.text"
            :id="data.index"
          />
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      
      <!-- <v-on:expandCard="showCard"/> -->
      <div> {{reached}} </div>
      
        <v-card 
          v-on:expandCard="showCard"
          v-if="dialog">
          <p> {{reached}}</p>
            <v-img
            dark
            class="white--text align-center"
            height="80%"
            :src="require('../assets/' + info[id].img)"
            :alt="`${info[id].title}`"
            
            >
            </v-img>
            <v-card-title>
            <p class="text-wrap">{{info[id].title}}</p>
            </v-card-title>
            
            <v-card-subtitle class="pb-0">{{info[id].tags}}</v-card-subtitle>

            <v-card-text class="text--primary">
            <div>{{info[id].text}}</div>
            </v-card-text>

            <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>

            <v-btn text color="primary" @click="dialog = false">Return</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
    </v-main>


  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import Card from '@/components/Card.vue'

export default {
  name: 'Projects',
  
    methods: {
      showCard(id) {
        this.dialog = true;
        this.id = id
        console.log(this.id)
      },
      reached() {
        console.log("reached")
      }
    }
</script>
```

What i want is to select a card and then pass the id of the card to the parent and then the parent renders that card above all other cards.

[Vue dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JXYk.png)

Comment: Will you try this syntax for me in the v-on listener

```v-on:expandCard="showCard "```   ->    ```@expand-card="showCard"```

Comment: But your this, reference also seems a but off, you have no data properties to save them in. (in the parent element).
Techincally it works, but it's not the right way to define data properties by adding them out of thin air.

You should have a data() { return { dialog: false, id: null }} for reference in the parent, and this is what you reference back down to the child, for potential style changes.

Comment: I may be confused because I haven't used Vuetify, but I'm not clear on the component hierarchy.  What is the name of the child component you are sending the emit from and why is it not listed in the components section of the parent?

Comment: The event is emitted from the `Card` component, but your listener is on a `v-card` in the parent component. The listener should be on `Card` instead.

Comment: @Abarth I removed the data component here to make it more readable but I had initialised dialog and id as you said. Also, I changed v-on to @ and it didn't fix the issue

Comment: @tony19 cheers mate that fixed it, Thanks! Put that down as an answer and ill mark it answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event is emitted from the `Card` component, but your listener is on a `v-card` in the parent component. The listener should be on `Card` instead:

```html
<!-- BEFORE: -->
<!-- <v-card v-on:expandCard="showCard"> -->

<Card v-on:expandCard="showCard">
```